# php preg_match problem

Tags: php

how can i get **41P86246HOH7C1G4A983321910HDL63U9** from the following with preg_match

input type="text" value="41P86246HOH7C1G4A983321910HDL63U9" id=""

Comment: `preg_match("41P86246HOH7C1G4A983321910HDL63U9", $str, $match");`?

Comment: Now it looks like you're trying to parse HTML with regular expressions, which is a huge no-no.

Comment: @Anon.: Your example won’t work since you forgot the delimiters. ;)

Comment: :) Though, it wasn't intended to be syntactically correct. Notice also the random `"` after `$match`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With something like this:

```
if(preg_match('@value="([^"]*)"@', $text, $m)){
    echo $m[1];
}
```

But you can also make something who split the string in each key with this value.

```
function attributes($text){
    $attrs = array();

    if(preg_match_all('@(\b[^=]*\b)\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"@', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)){
        foreach($matches as $m){
            $attrs[$m[1]] = $m[2];
        }
     }

     return $attrs;
 }

 // Use like this
 $attrs = attributes('input value="bla"');
 if(isset($attrs['value'])){
     echo $attrs['value'];
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
DOMDocument::loadHTML("<$input>")->getElementsByTagName('input')
    ->item(0)->getAttribute('value');
```

Answer (score 3):

What about something like this :

```
$str = 'input type="text" value="41P86246HOH7C1G4A983321910HDL63U9" id=""';
$m = array();
if (preg_match('#value="([^"]+)"#', $str, $m)) {
    var_dump($m[1]);
}
```

Which will match everything between the double quotes that come with `value`, and get you :

```
string '41P86246HOH7C1G4A983321910HDL63U9' (length=33)
```

*But, as a sidenote : if you are trying to "parse" HTML with regex, it's generally not the "best" way ; HTML is not quite regular enough for regex...*

Comment: but i want only 41P86246HOH7C1G4A983321910HDL63U9 not extra characters

Comment: what "extra character" do you get ? The regex I posted only gave ...U9 as a result ;; the other informations displayed arround that string in my answer are the output of var_dump (with Xdebug installed).

Answer (score 2):

Simply, without extra characters:

```
preg_match('/(?<=value=")[0-9A-Za-z]+/', $str, $match);
```

Your result is in `$match[0]`;

Answer (score 0):

don't even have to use regex. Just use PHP's string methods

```
$str='input type="text" value="41P86246HOH7C1G4A983321910HDL63U9" id=""';
$s = explode(" ",$str);
// go through each element, find "value"
foreach($s as $a=>$b){
    if(strpos($b,"value")!==FALSE){
        $find = explode("=",$b);
        print $find[1];
    }
}
```